# pd.merge : trying to merge Dataframes with same columns names

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I know this is a simple issue but I am stuck in it by quite some time. 
I have two `DataFrame`, that have thousand os rows but here is a sample :

```
df1 = 

Name    Value    Date
x        0.04    2014-01-02
x        0.03    2014-01-03
x        0.02    2014-01_05
x        0.02    2014-01-07
(...)    (...)      (...)
y        0.002   2014-01-01
y        0.001   2014-01-02
y        0.003   2014-01-03
y        0.004   2014-01-07
(...)     (...)     (...)
z        0.003   2014-01-02
z        0.003   2014-01-05
z        0.004   2014-01-07
(...)     (...)      (...)
```

And another `Dataframe` :

```
df2 = 

  Name    Value    Date
    x        0.04    2015-01-02
    x        0.03    2015-01-03
    x        0.02    2015-01_05
    x        0.02    2015-01-07
    (...)    (...)      (...)
    y        0.002   2015-01-01
    y        0.001   2015-01-02
    y        0.003   2015-01-03
    y        0.004   2015-01-07
    (...)     (...)     (...)
    z        0.003   2015-01-02
    z        0.003   2015-01-05
    z        0.004   2015-01-07
    (...)     (...)      (...)
```

what I want :

```
df3=
   Name    Value    Date
    x        0.04    2014-01-02
    x        0.03    2014-01-03
    x        0.02    2014-01_05
    x        0.02    2014-01-07
    x        0.04    2015-01-02
    x        0.03    2015-01-03
    x        0.02    2015-01_05
    x        0.02    2015-01-07
    (...)    (...)      (...)
    y        0.002   2014-01-01
    y        0.001   2014-01-02
    y        0.003   2014-01-03
    y        0.004   2014-01-07
    y        0.002   2015-01-01
    y        0.001   2015-01-02
    y        0.003   2015-01-03
    y        0.004   2015-01-07
    (...)     (...)     (...)
    z        0.003   2014-01-02
    z        0.003   2014-01-05
    z        0.004   2014-01-07
    z        0.003   2015-01-02
    z        0.003   2015-01-05
    z        0.004   2015-01-07
    (...)     (...)      (...)
```

1) when I merge , if `"name"` is not present in 2014 data, I want it to not be present in my df3, and The same with my 2015 data.

In other words, I want only the `"Name"` that has value in both my `Dataframes`.

What I tried :

`a= df1.merge(df2,how="inner")`
And

```
frames= [df1,df2]
df3= pd.concat([frames],axis=1)
```

but what I am given as output :

```
df3 = 

Value_x     Date_y    Name    Value_y    Date_y 
  0.03    2014-01-02    x        0.04    2015-01-02
  0.02    2014-01-05    x        0.03    2015-01-03
  0.03    2014-01-06    x        0.02    2015-01_05
  0.03    2014-01-07    x        0.02    2015-01-07
  (...)     (...)     (...)      (...)     (...)    
   0.02   2014-01-03    y        0.002   2015-01-01
   0.01   2014-01-07    y        0.001   2015-01-02
   0.02   2014-01-06    y        0.003   2015-01-03
   00.2   2014-01-07    y        0.004   2015-01-07
  (...)     (...)     (...)      (...)     (...)
   0.03   2014-01-02   z        0.003   2015-01-02
   0.01   2014-01-04   z        0.003   2015-01-05
   0.03   2014-01-05   z        0.004   2015-01-07
  (...)      (...)     (...)     (...)   (...)
```

Comment: should you be using axis = 0 with pd.concat?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.append`: You can do

```py
#...

df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

# or more dfs list
df = df1.append([df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
```

for more info see documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Value', right_on='Value')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to match *days* from 2014 and 2015. If some day is missing from 2014 or 2015, it shouldn't be in the resulting frame.

Note, in this example I added `2014-01-08` date as name `z` to `df1` - it will not be in the final dataframe, because `2015-01-08` doesn't exist with this name in `df2`):

```
import pandas as pd

name_1 = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z']
value_1 = [0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.002, 0.001, 0.003, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.004, 0.009]
date_1 = ['2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-05', '2014-01-07', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-07', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-05', '2014-01-07', '2014-01-08']

name_2 = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z']
value_2 = [0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.002, 0.001, 0.003, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.004]
date_2 = ['2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-07']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':name_1, 'Value':value_1, 'Date': date_1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':name_2, 'Value':value_2, 'Date': date_2})

df1['days'] = df1['Date'].str.split(r'\d{4}-(\d+-\d+)', expand=True)[1]
df2['days'] = df2['Date'].str.split(r'\d{4}-(\d+-\d+)', expand=True)[1]

df = pd.merge( df1,  df2, on=['Name', 'days'] )

df = df1[ df1.set_index( ['Name', 'Date'] ).index.isin( df.set_index( ['Name', 'Date_x']).index ) ].append(
        df2[ df2.set_index( ['Name', 'Date'] ).index.isin( df.set_index( ['Name', 'Date_y']).index ) ]
    ).sort_values(['Name', 'Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
del df['days']

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Name  Value        Date
0     x  0.040  2014-01-02
1     x  0.030  2014-01-03
2     x  0.020  2014-01-05
3     x  0.020  2014-01-07
4     x  0.040  2015-01-02
5     x  0.030  2015-01-03
6     x  0.020  2015-01-05
7     x  0.020  2015-01-07
8     y  0.002  2014-01-01
9     y  0.001  2014-01-02
10    y  0.003  2014-01-03
11    y  0.004  2014-01-07
12    y  0.002  2015-01-01
13    y  0.001  2015-01-02
14    y  0.003  2015-01-03
15    y  0.004  2015-01-07
16    z  0.003  2014-01-02
17    z  0.003  2014-01-05
18    z  0.004  2014-01-07
19    z  0.003  2015-01-02
20    z  0.003  2015-01-05
21    z  0.004  2015-01-07
```