# Pandas: correct way to merge dataframes (not with pd.merge() apparently)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I read another question that probably has some similar problem ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427034/pd-merge-trying-to-merge-dataframes-with-same-columns-names)) but I couldn't understand the answer.

Consider 2 dataframes defined like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : ['a','b','c','d'],
    'B': [1,np.nan,np.nan,4]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : ['a','c','b','d'],
    'B' : [np.nan, 8, 9, np.nan]
```

I want to merge them to fill blank cells. At first I used

```
df1.merge(df2, on='A')
```

but this caused my df1 to have 2 different columns named `B_x` and `B_y`. I also tried with different parameters for the .merge() method but still couldn't solve the issue.
The final dataframe should look like this one

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : ['a','b','c','d'],
    'B': [1,9,8,4]
})
```

Do you know what's the most logic way to do that?
I think that pd.concat() should be a useful tool for this job but I have no idea on how to apply it.

EDIT:
I modified values so that 'A' columns don't have the same order in both dataframes. This should avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `fillna` instead:

```
new_df = df1.fillna(df2)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   A    B
0  a  1.0
1  b  9.0
2  c  8.0
3  d  4.0
```

Here's a different solution:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='A', suffixes=(';',';')).pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.str.strip(';'), axis=1)).groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
```

The semicolons (`;`) are arbitrary; you can use any character as long as it doesn't appear in any columns names.

Comment: thanks, but this method doesnt consider the values in column A. It fills blank cells in the order they appear. In this case they appear In the same order in both df but in general they could not. For example what if `df2['A']=['a','c','b','d']` ?

Comment: I managed to use it anyway in this way   
`df1.fillna(value=df2.sort_values('A', ignore_index=True))` .   
But still maybe there's some other way

Comment: I added another solution to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` the values from df2:

```
df1['B'] = df1['B'].fillna(df1['A'].map(df2.set_index('A')['B']))
```

output:

```
   A    B
0  a  1.0
1  b  9.0
2  c  8.0
3  d  4.0
```

###### Alternative

if the values in A are unique, you can merge only the column A of df1 and `combine_first`:

```
df1 = df1.combine_first(df1[['A']].merge(df2))
```